# Library version issues and conflicts

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, shared-libraries, libraries

Dear expert community,

I so often face problems that software will not compile or work because libraries (specifically .so files) are too new.
If I try to install the old library (apt-get on Ubuntu) I can get errors that it is "not installable" because of conflicts...

So following problems arise in my mind:
1) how to install old libraries/packages together with newer ones for example on Arch Linux or Ubuntu Linux ?
2) how to avoid conflicts: the older library should be used (linked) only with the "problematic old" software and/or if I specify this explicitly ?
3) how can I check with cmake, make or the autotools if a specific (old) library version is installed and in case not automatically get it and install it and use it without conflict with a newer version ?

Thank to any expert for a help

Answer (score 0):

1. Linux package managers normally don't allow installing multiple versions of the same package. You have to install older versions yourself, by hand, from source, preferably to some private place like `/usr/old-versions`.
2. You link problematic software like this:
   `<link command> -L /usr/old-versions/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/old-versions/lib`
   and it automatically uses the old version of the library.
3. There is no way to do that automatically.

Note that you may need to compile against older versions of library headers too, not just link against old versions of the libraries.